# Angular universal - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at new ApplicationRef

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

So i have a problem, i get error:
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at new ApplicationRef

My webpack.server.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(ts|js)$/, loader: 'regexp-replace-loader', options: { match: { pattern: '\\[(Mouse|Keyboard|Focus)Event\\]', flags: 'g' }, replaceWith: '[]', } },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {} 
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "jinni-angular"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/browser",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "images",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "images",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "jinni-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.6",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "compression": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "latest",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "latest",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "latest",
    "ng-custom-select": "^1.0.4",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "ng2-breadcrumbs": "^0.1.281",
    "ng2-carouselamos": "^3.2.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ng4-intl-phone": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.2.2",
    "ngx-dropdown": "0.0.22",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "node": "^9.11.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "regexp-replace-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "serve": "^6.5.3",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.36",
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

and at last server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});
global['Event'] = null;
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

after use serve:universal everything is fine but when i go to localhost:4000 i get an error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new ApplicationRef

Any ideas?

full error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new ApplicationRef (/.../dist/server.js:5838:64)
    at _createClass (/..../dist/server.js:10145:20)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (/..../dist/server.js:10115:26)
    at initNgModule (/..../dist/server.js:10051:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (/..../dist/server.js:10767:9)
    at Object.createNgModuleRef (/..../dist/server.js:10756:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (/..../dist/server.js:13289:25)
    at /..../dist/server.js:5589:43
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/...../dist/server.js:147664:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (/...../dist/server.js:4931:33)
```

Comment: Try downgrading Angular components to Angular 5. I also get this error with Angular 6, haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I have this problem with Angular 5. I think it's not the Angular version but the ng-select version.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I am facing same issue on upgrading to angular 6 from angular 5.